# Unity 2D - Get value from list of class by class variable's value

Tags: c#, xml, list, class, unity-game-engine

My Xml loader saves data from xml file to list of class . Dialog is class with 2 properties: id and text, where are save content of xml file. I want to get "text" variable value in DialogLoader.cs from list in DialogContainer.cs by value of id variable. How can I do that? It's probably easy, but i don't know how.

**dialogs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DialogCollection>
  <Dialogs>
    <Dialog id="1">
      <Text>Hello my friend</Text>
    </Dialog>
    <Dialog id="2">
      <Text>Hello my grandma</Text>
    </Dialog>
    <Dialog id="3">
      <Text>Hello my grandpa</Text>
    </Dialog>
  </Dialogs>
</DialogCollection>
```

**DialogLoader.cs**

```
public class DialogLoader : MonoBehaviour
{

public const string path = "dialogs";

void Start()
{
    DialogContainer dc = DialogContainer.Load(path);
//There I want to get text for example by id 1 (Hello my friend)
    foreach (Dialog item in dc.dialogs)
    {
        print(item.text);
    }
}
```

**DialogContainer.cs**

```
[XmlRoot("DialogCollection")]
public class DialogContainer
{

    [XmlArray("Dialogs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Dialog")]
    public List<Dialog> dialogs = new List<Dialog>();

    public static DialogContainer Load(string path)
    {
        TextAsset _xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DialogContainer));

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(_xml.text);

        DialogContainer dialogs = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as DialogContainer;


        reader.Close();

        return dialogs;
    }


}
```

**Dialog.cs**

```
public class Dialog
{

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string id;

    [XmlElement("Text")]
    public string text;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either add a Dictionary like

```
[XmlRoot("DialogCollection")]
public class DialogContainer
{
    [XmlArray("Dialogs")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Dialog")]
    public List<Dialog> dialogs = new List<Dialog>();

    public Dictionary<string, string> IdToText = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static DialogContainer Load(string path)
    {
        TextAsset _xml = Resources.Load<TextAsset>(path);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DialogContainer));

        // use a better variable name since "dialogs" is also a field of it
        DialogContainer dialogContainer;

        // use "using" for disposables
        using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(_xml.text))
        {
            dialogContainer = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as DialogContainer;
        }

        // reset dictionary
        dialogContainer.IdToText.Clear();
        foreach(var entry in dialogContainer.dialogs)
        {
            dialogContainer.IdToText.Add(entry.id, entry.text);
        }

        return dialogContainer;
    }
}
```

Than you can later use e.g.

```
aDialogContainer.idTotext["1"];
```

note that this will throw an exception is searched key is not in the dictionary! So refer to the solution below.

---

Anther option is to implement a getter method instead of the dictionary to look up the correct text on the fly using [LINQ: FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
public string IdtoText(string id)
{
    var foundDialog = dialogs.FirstOrDefault(dialog => string.Equals(dialog.id, id));

    //         here you can decide whether to        |
    //         return null or "" if no element found v 
    return foundDialog != null ? foundDialog.text : "";
}
```

Than you would use

```
aDialogContainer.IdTotext("1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to filter a list of dialogs and simply return the first one matching your condiction.

Something like this:

```
public Dialog GetSingleDialog(string id, List<Dialog> dialogs){

return dialogs.Where(x=>x.id==id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

You can use like this:

```
DialogContainer dc = DialogContainer.Load(path);
//Get list of dialogs
var dialogs=dc.dialogs;
var theDialog=GetSingleDialog("1",dialogs);
```

//Get your text

```
Debug.Log(theDialog.Text);
```

Comment: note that `Where` doesn't return a single value but instead an `IEnumerable<Dialog>`

Comment: note that [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns a an `IEnumerable<Dialog>`, **not** a single value

Comment: Somehow, I felt I typed `FirstOrDefault();` Thanks for calling my attention to that.

Comment: in this case .. why the unecessary call of `Where` .. you can diractly use `FirstOrDefault` on the original list. You also would have to make the method either `static` and use `var theDialog = DialogContainer.GetSingleDialog("1", dialogs);` or use `var theDialog = dc.GetSingleDialog("1", dialogs);` .. however in this case it is a bit redundant to have to get the List reference first ...